Run Job Against Different Environment On Jenkins Manually
On jenkins I want to run my test suit against different environment manually like (stage ,qa ,prod ) .How to achieve the same? also I Want to map enviormnent with special group of test cases .Like To run regression group when I select qa ,and sanity on prod .
I tried using enviorment paramaters ,but I am not able to map group against environment .

Add an input parameter with the target environment. Then, create a map with the environment-testsuite mapping.
Something like:
def testsuiteMap = [
  staging: 'e2e',
  qa: 'regression',
  prod: 'sanity'
]

pipeline {
  parameters {
    choice name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: ['staging', 'qa', 'prod']
  }

  stages {
    stage('run') {
      steps {
        script {
          def testsuiteToRun = testsuiteMap[params.ENVIRONMENT]
          echo "Testsuite to run: ${testsuiteToRun}"
          sh "<put_command_here>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

